# Извлечь данные из SessionStorage

Tags: java, json

При открытии сайта некоторые данные хранятся в SessionStorage в JSON. Как их оттуда можно вытащить?

Т.е. при запуски приложения на JAVA грузится определенная страница, а из SessionStorage данные должны парситься, например, в файл.

Comment: Вы хотите это делать с помощью `JS`?

Comment: Желательно в JAVA

Comment: Т.е. при запуски приложения на JAVA, грузится определенная страница, а из  SessionStorage данные должны парситься, например в файл.